# Join doesn't working in LINQ in Devexpress XPO

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have used persistance class and used following LINQ query :

```
XPQuery<Students> objStudentQuery = new XPQuery<Students>(XpoDefault.Session);
XPQuery<ExamDetails> objExamDetailsQuery = new XPQuery<ExamDetails>(XpoDefault.Session);

var ExamDetails = from exm in objExamDetailsQuery
                          join student in objStudentQuery on exm.StudentId equals student.StudentId
                          select new { student.FirstName, student.LastName, exm.ExamName, exm.Marks, exm.Date };
```

but it throws an error saying. "Specified Method is not Supported"

How can i get data from two table using XPO Persistance Class?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

XPO does not provide capabilities to join data using standard SQL approaches. Instead, it provides an [Associations](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XPO/CustomDocument2257) concept. I suggest that you review the [Specifics of joining data from multiple tables in XPO](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/K18431.aspx) Knowledge Base article describing an XPO way of joining data.