# How to display data from two tables in a SQL Server database in a gridview?

Tags: sql, sql-server, gridview, join, devexpress

I want show data in a gridview from two tables that have a relationship but it show only some column in table 1. I using an `INNER JOIN` query.

- `dept` (`IDD, deptname`)
- `person` (`ID, name, birthday, address, IDD`)

I want to display the columns `ID, name, deptname` in a gridview, but `deptname` is not showing any value.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you **show us** your `INNER JOIN` query?

Comment: yes, "Select ID, name, deptname from person inner join dept on person.IDD = dept.IDD". I was searched in google, it said "add unbound coluums" but I don't know add unbound coluum from database with inner join. Thanks!

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure it's a sql problem, and not a code problem in your visual studio? Show us how you get and put values into your gridview.

Answer (score 0):

The select query is straightforward:

```
select 
   person.ID,
   person.name,
   department.deptname
from person
inner join department on person.IDD = department.IDD
```

If you aren't getting any results, then perhaps no records meet your join criteria.  You can change the inner join to a full outer join and examine the results to check if this is the case.

Comment: I doing project with visual basic.net. Visual studio 2010 and Devexpress tools. I want show data on gridview but I can'n show from two table

Comment: is this a possible duplicate of this question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240065/join-doesnt-working-in-linq-in-devexpress-xpo

Comment: [link (http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/CustomDocument1477). I was read it, but it get value from current collums in table. Please give me code get data from two table. Thanks!